# Is there an ASCII character that is an underscore and an overscore at the same time?

Tags: ascii

I am looking for a character that will be the addition of an underscore (`_`) and an overscore (`‾`):

```
_+‾
```

Is there such a character?

Comment: Plain ASCII?  No, there isn't.  You can look through the list of available characters here: https://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: If you can use unicode then both the overscore ‾ (U+203E) and underscore _ (U+005F) are combining characters. You should be able to use them to get what you want.

Comment: Characters U+035E and U+035F seems also suitable for combining. Run Charmap, Character map or Characters depending on OS and use the Find/Search function in these.

Comment: Search for e.g. BOX, BLOCK, LINE, SQUARE, DOT, SPOT, DASH, MACRON. Also U+3193 might close to what you want